# How to change HTTP request version to 1.0 using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

In C# I can override WebClient.GetWebRequest method in order to change HTTP version.

```
protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)  
{  
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(uri);        
    request.ProtocolVersion = System.Net.HttpVersion.Version10;  

    return request;  
}
```

I have to change HTTP request version to 1.0 before invoking web service using New-WebServiceProxy.

Is there a way to change this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the ProtocolVersion field to version10. Like so,

```
$hr = [system.net.httpwebrequest]::create("http://www.example.com")
$hr.ProtocolVersion = [system.net.httpversion]::version10
```

Mind you, unlike C#, Powershell (and .Net API bindings) are note case sensitive.